# How to access TFAT from Windows desktop?

Tags: filesystems

I have a windows CE device which is using TFAT as a filesystem for its SDIO card.

I wish to read/write that SDIO card on Windows 7.

What's the best way to go about this?

Thanks.

Comment: Tfat is just Fat with better recoverability. sort of a journaling for fat. msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd229245.aspx It is just as readable as Fat? It is only when you wish to format it, that the standard system cant just do that. In the link there you can see that my simple explaination, is run over by complexity, but working with a Tfat initilaised flash was not a problem?   That said, the tfat is used in portable systems where BRICKING is possible, so I wouldnt want to mess up your device.

Comment: After looking on the web at the problems,  now I just feel like I missed all the fun, because I didnt even think about it , I had converted to fat, played with it, converted to fat32, messed with cluster size. Then reconverted back to tfat formatting on the device itself. changed anything I wanted, and ignored that it was special. I certannly had 2 Full backups of the data. There was nothing special about it in that case because in THAT device (prior to the changes in CE6 devices) it was not primary, they still had the ROM.